# 2nd usb audio card - unable to set as default on OdroidXU4 - application still uses hdmi sound

Tags: ubuntu, usb, audio, hdmi

Ubuntu minimal 20.04 LTS running on OdroidXU4. So no desktop environment.

```
root@odroid:~# cat /proc/asound/cards
0 [OdroidXU4      ]: Odroid-XU4 - Odroid-XU4
                  Odroid-XU4
1 [Device         ]: USB-Audio - USB PnP Sound Device
                  C-Media Electronics Inc. USB PnP Sound Device at usb-xhci-hcd.3.auto-1.2, full
```

I modified asound.conf to set the usb audio as default

```
GNU nano 4.8                                /etc/asound.conf                                           
pcm.!default {
    type plug
    slave {
            pcm "hw:1,0"
    }
}

ctl.!default {
    type hw
    card 1
}
```

If I now execute

```
speaker-test -t wav -c 2
```

the 'front left' and 'front right' are played back to me so I assume this means that the usb audio card is now the default one.

If I start a process the audio is still coming through the hdmi.

I also tried - besides a ton of other things - to edit the /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf and setting the `options snd-usb-audio index=0`
two times, as it appears two times.

If I do that I loose the usb sound card upon reboot. If I set it to `options snd-usb-audio index=1` it reappears but the situation remains the same. I just tried that because normally it is being specified as `options snd-usb-audio index=-2` to prohibit 'abnormal cards' to become the default and I assumed it was interfering with me wanting to set is as the default.

I took care to revert non working changes so the system is audio wise in the exact state as described here. The defaults with the described changes. The OS originally comes from 18.04 -> 19.04 -> 20.04 as 18.04 is the latest image I could download from hardkernel for the sbc.
I did loose sound after the distribution upgrades. A known problem apparently. I repaired it after a few attempts as being described in a lot of posts.

My question : How do I make all the applications use the usb audio device please?

Comment: 1) Do you run Pulseaudio? 2) Which "process" do you start that causes audio through HDMI? Does this "process" use Pulseaudio, ALSA, Jack, ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run Pulseaudio anyway, don't mess with the ALSA settings (which say to use Pulseaudio for ALSA-only applications), instead use `pavucontrol` or `pacmd` to set the default sink and/or the sink of a specific application in Pulseaudio.

Pulseaudio has a database that will assign the same sink to an application the next time the application starts, so setting the default sink in Pulseaudio will only get picked app for applications that have never run before.